# Why Does My Code Scrape The First Record Only?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath, css-selectors

My code goes into a website, and clicks on records which causes drop downs.

My current code only prints the first drop down record, and not the others.

**For example**, the first record of the webpage when clicked, drops down 1 record. This record is shown attached. This is also the first and only dropdown record that gets printed as my output.
[image]

The code prints this

How do I get it to pull all drop down titles?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()


for x in range (1,2):
    driver.get(f'https://library.iaslc.org/conference-program?product_id=24&author=&category=&date=&session_type=&session=&presentation=&keyword=&available=&cme=&page={x}')
    time.sleep(4)
    productlist_length = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='accordin_title']"))
    
for i in range(1, productlist_length + 1):

        product = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='accordin_title'])[" + str(i) + "]")
        title = product.find_element_by_xpath('.//h4').text.strip()
        print(title)

        buttonToClick = product.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="sign"]')
        buttonToClick.click()
        time.sleep(5)

        subProduct=driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//li[@class='sub_accordin_presentation']")
        otherTitle=subProduct.find_element_by_xpath('.//h4').text.strip()
        print(otherTitle)
```

Comment: Do you understand that `range(1,2)` produces exactly one element, "1"?  If you want the numbers 1 and 2, then just say `for x in (1,2):`.

Comment: That part of my code is for the number of pages. If you look at the line under it, it just applies for the URL. It does not impact the issue I am referring to.

Comment: Can you show a sample output? "the first record only" can imply many meanings, such as there is only one output as one record, or there are many outputs repeating the same record.

Comment: @burningalc example has now been attached.

Comment: Is `productlist_length`'s value correct?

Comment: @burningalc Yes, looks correct to me. It is 10, so not sure why it stops after the first record.

Comment: Can you try to include a `print(i)` in the loop to see whether it's actually looping 10 times?

Comment: is this syntax correct? `"(//div[@class='accordin_title'])[" + str(i) + "]"` for `find_element_by_xpath`?  I've been seeing examples like `"//div[@class='accordin_title']"` so is it possible that it's ignoring the selector after the end parenthesis and you should be matching on `"//div[@class='accordin_title'][i]"` to actually iterate through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need selenium at all. Not sure what all the info is that you are after but the following shows you that the content is available, from within those expand blocks, with the response from a simple `requests.get()`.:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

r = requests.get('https://library.iaslc.org/conference-program?product_id=24&author=&category=&date=&session_type=&session=&presentation=&keyword=&available=&cme=&page=1')
soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')
sessions = soup.select('#accordin > ul > li')

for session in sessions:
    print(session.select_one('h4').text)
    sub_session = session.select('.sub_accordin_presentation')
    if sub_session:
        print([re.sub(r'[\n\s]+', ' ', i.text) for i in sub_session])
    print()
    print()
```

Comment: You seem to be able to do these flawlessly, is there a course or something you reccommend?

Comment: Just study some html and learn how to use the elements and network tabs of browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
productlist_length = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="jscroll-inner"]/ul/li'))
for product in productlist_length:
    title = product.find_element_by_xpath('(.//*[@class="accordin_title"]/div)[3]/h4').text
```

Comment: for product in productlist_length:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

is the error i get

Comment: remove 'len' function

Comment: Yes, when i remove len it works. However, still only pulls the first drop down :l

Comment: Update, i changed line subproduct=driver.find_element_by_xpath to -> subproduct=product.find_element_by_xpath and it seems to be working better by grabbing the first drop down of every record. There are some records, that have many drop downs. So the code still needs to grab all elements